# Trapezoidal wave rms value calculation

Tags: wave

Does anybody know how to calculate this wave RMS value?

The answer is

[image]

[image]

I use Mathcad to prove it but I still can not get the answer.

Hope someone can give me help.

Comment: Ugh. I got a similar problem at signal theory (but it was worse, they asked for the Fourier transform). Bad memories:D  The general theory is that you attack your waveform by pieces and then add the piece together (superposition rings a bell?). You can find a similar worked out example here https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-a-trapezoidal-waveform/

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio  Thanks for your reply, but I think the link is different. I know how to derive the Trazpezoidal at the 0.

Comment: @Jitter456 Can you show your calculations? Maybe we can pin-point where you went wrong.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  I got the answer thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the general formula for the RMS-voltage is given by:

$$\overline{\text{I}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\left(\text{I}\left(t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t}\tag1$$

So, in your case:

$$\overline{\text{I}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}_\text{on}+\text{T}_\text{off}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^{\text{T}_\text{on}}\left(-\text{I}_0\right)^2\space\text{d}t+\int_0^{\text{T}_\text{off}}\left(\text{I}_\text{a}+\frac{\text{I}_\text{b}-\text{I}_\text{a}}{\text{T}_\text{off}}\cdot t\right)^2\space\text{d}t\right\}}\tag2$$

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out

Comment: @Jitter456 you're welcome